# Qt translations issue while dealing with QUiloader

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using QUiloader to dynamically load .ui files which are not listed in the .pro project file.

So far so good. The issue is that `lupdate` only translates what it see under the .pro file. I'm running it with the following command:

```
lupdate project.pro -ts tr_language.ts
```

So I'm missing all the text in the .ui file.

I managed to discover lupdate can translate the widget.ui if I push the following command:

```
lupdate widget.ui -ts tr_language.ts
```

Doing so I can get the .ui stuff translated.

What's the problem? I can do only one of the above mentioned approaches, as they overwrite each other.

Is there a smarter approach for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a smarter approach for this issue?

Simple: Do not overwrite the file.
Just use

```
lupdate widget.ui -ts tr_widget_language.ts
```

or any other name for your ts.
This way you have two files which do not overwrite each other.

After that you can use:

```
lrelease [options] ts-files [-qm qm-file]
```

It mentions ts-files as argument. With this you should be able to compile multiple *.ts files into one *.qm File.

Otherwise you would have to load the second *.qm File in your application.

Comment: You can make one extra *.ts that contains all info from all your *.ui files. That will add one *.qm file that needs to be loaded by your application.

Comment: Or you bundle all your *.ts files into one *.qm file. Have a look at lRelease documentation: http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/linguist-manager.html

Comment: Oops... I just deleted my previous comment, didn't noted your comments, sorry. I managed to install both .ts, that' good. But, I didn't got the idea about how to bundle all the .ts in one .qm (Ctrl+f "bundle" in the documentation link gives nothing).

Comment: I think you can use: `lrelease [options] ts-files [-qm qm-file]`. It mentions ts-file*s* as argument. So you should be able to compile multiple *.ts files into one *.qm. Otherwise you would have to load the second *.qm in your application.